# What is the role of the coordinator in DistBelief's Sandblaster L-BFGS?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the Sandblaster L-BFGS. How often is the entire parameter vector in the same shared memory? What exactly is the purpose of the parameter server? And the coordinator?

Here's the diagram:

[image: https://imgur.com/3wmv19x]

Here's a link to the original paper: http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4687-large-scale-distributed-deep-networks.pdf